# Why catkin_make doesn't create executables?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, build, begginer-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to build the client-server C++ tutorial with catkin_make it doesn't create any executables, I think I have everything else in order.
I had followed every single step in the previous tutorials, the worspace is correctly configured, the CMakeLists.txt seems in order as the package.xml.

Here is the link to the tutorial.http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29

And the output when I try to build and then execute.

```
viki@c3po:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws/

viki@c3po:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make

Base path: /home/viki/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/viki/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/viki/catkin_ws/build"
####

viki@c3po:~$ rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named add_two_ints_server below /home/viki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials
viki@c3po:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206103/why-catkin_make-doesn%27t-create-executables?/) by [Romerop](https://answers.ros.org/users/22005/romerop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-27**:
This is not enough information to be able to help you. Please edit your question to include a link to the tutorial you're following. Every command you're running and the exact console output, what's in your workspace, and any other relevant information to reproduce your problem. wiki.ros.org/Support

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2015-03-30**:
Could you add your workspace environment variables ? You can have them with
export | grep ROS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output at the bottom tells you exactly what the problem is. The syntax of rosrun is `rosrun PACKAGE EXECUTABLE [ARGS]`. You are not providing an executable to rosrun.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Romerop](https://answers.ros.org/users/22005/romerop/) on 2015-03-30**:
Sorry I wrote that incorrectly, anyway when I write "rosrun begginer_tutorials add_two_ints_server" it says the same thing, add_two_ints_sever is the executable  created when building add_two_ints_server.cpp, but the problem is that the executable is never created. Also there is no need of arguments

**Comment by [Romerop](https://answers.ros.org/users/22005/romerop/) on 2015-03-30**:
I edited the question so you can see the output when I write the correct command

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps you are not adding an executable in your CMakeLists.txt.

Do you have this line in CMakeLists.txt: `add_executable(executable_name source_file_name.cpp` ?

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Romerop](https://answers.ros.org/users/22005/romerop/) on 2015-03-30**:
Yes I do, as specified in the tutorial. CMakeFile.txt:add_executable(add_two_ints_server src/add_two_ints_server.cpp)